# Grab only the first or the last match

Tags: regex, xml, duplicates, abap

I need some help with regex which does not work perfect:

```
/(?<=([H|h][i|I])+\w+\>)(.*)(?=(\<))/
```

I have got a few XML, I need to filter out the `errorMessage` and the `errorCode` from those XMLs. Not all XML have the same syntax. Sometimes `errorMessage` sometimes `ERRORTEXT` sometimes `Error_Messages` is the tag name in my XMLs.

An example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" endcoding=UTF-8"?>
<n0:szemelyKutyaFuleResponsexmlns:prx="urn:sap.comproxy:SWP:/1SAI/TREASE1243804269AE457508F4:753" mmlns:n0="http://csajgeneratorws.tny.interfesz.kok.lo/">
    <return>
        <tanzakciosAzonosito>46981682-4637-49d2-bd4d-dcfff543742ed</tanzakciosAzonosito>
        <erdmeny>HIBAS</eredmeny>
        <errorCode>TSH08</errorCode>
        <errorMessage>Azonosítószám már hozzá lett rendelve üzleti partnerhez</errorMessage>
    </return>
</n0:szemelyKutyaFuleResponse>
```

I think I need to create two regex:

- One to find the text `TSH08` in `errorCode`
- and another regex to find `Azonosítószám már hozzá lett rendelve üzleti partnerhez` in `errorMessage`!

Pls help THX

Comment: Why Regex? Use Xml classes for such of requirements.

Comment: Use an XML parser, then you can easily traverse the hierarchy

Comment: The xml are stored in a HANA 4 DB this is a part from an abap develep program. I need this information to store later in an avl list or put back to a table...

Comment: I haven t got a fix hierarcy in the xml structur. Like wrote befor the tag-s are just dimilar but not the same, and by the xml hierarcy the same. PLS help me write a proper regex!

Comment: Parsing XML using regular expressions is almost as futile as [parsing HTML with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). You should really use an XML parser for this. Fortunately there is already a bunch of standard classes for this: The [iXML library](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/index.htm?file=abenabap_ixml_lib.htm).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the content of each tag, which is what I understood from your question, then perhaps something like these:

For the first regex:

- `<errorCode>([^<>]+)</errorCode>` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QMVt1d/1)
- `(?<=<errorCode>)[^<>]+(?=</errorCode>)` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gWNjKW/1)

For the second regex:

- `<errorMessage>([^<>]+)</errorMessage>` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uUjhhb/1)
- `(?<=<errorMessage>)[^<>]+(?=</errorMessage>)` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/atc3YA/1)

You also can merge them with an `|` between the two if you don't care about the tag.

A `|` can also be added if the tag's name might differ like this:
`<(?:errorMessage|ERRORTEXT|Error_Messages)>([^<>]+)</(?:errorMessage|ERRORTEXT|Error_Messages)>` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3trY1G/1)